# Is there some type of connection between Mavis and Zeref?

Tags: fairy-tail

In opening 10 of Fairy Tail at 1:15 we see Mavis and Zeref walking towards each other. When their lines of vision meet, a look of deja vu appears on their faces, indicating that they have meet before. Do they know each other and what is their connection? Did they once love each other? (That's the speculation on my part.)

Please watch the **opening of Fairy Tail, Number 10** [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=3sdm2CEhW7A#t=75) first **before** answering my question so you have a better understanding on what I am asking in my question.

Answers are appreciated.

Comment: not disclosed till now. neither in manga nor in anime.

Comment: i think mavis and zeref were good friends .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Until now there's still no flash back about their relationship.</s>

From chapter 450 'The One And Only This World' it was confirmed that

> [image] 
> Mavis and Zeref love each other, and because of Zeref's curse, Mavis died

Comment: They could have quite possibly been rivals at one time judging on boths abilities and powers.

Answer (score 8):

I think Zeref and Mavis had a thing. You know how Zeref said one day, that he realized the meaning of life and stopped all of his bad ways? Well, I think that day was the day Mavis died. Possibly killed by Zeref himself. He may have felt terrible and realized that he needed to be stopped. So as he awaits Natsu to get stronger, he stays near Mavis, enjoying her presences till the day comes.

Comment: good prediction i guess. +1 to this

Comment: Lets just say I never thought of this before. +1 for this.

Comment: About the Natsu-part: Zeref stopped mass-murdering "some" time ago (depite plotting something again now). But, the possibility of time travels aside, he has an abnormal long lifespan. What if he managed to become completely immortal regarding age during his "evil-time" and needs someone to surpass him / kill him to be able to die? ...

Comment: It is interesting to see that **this is exactly what happened** more than a year after you posted it...

Answer (score 3):

Yes. They know each other. In *Fairy Tail Zero* chapter 7, they met at a lake in the forest.

[image]

Zeref taught Mavis, Zeira, Precht, Warrod, and Yuri Dreyar their magic. The two were friends and Zeref hinted that it was because of him (directly or indirectly) that Mavis died.

Comment: If you could find a link that supports your answer. Please add it. Thanks and welcome to Stack.

Comment: Actually from the Fairy Tail manga, it isn't clear whether Mavis actually died or if she was only sealed away, like with Deliora. Especially since you can see her spirit lingering. It could be that her "spirit" is actually one of her illusions and that she communicates through her illusions while being sealed. I'm getting pretty hyped about her powers tbh. Too bad FT zero is only released montly.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest chapter, number 448:

> In the two last pages, Mavis appears and wants to tell everyone in the Guild the truth about Lumen Histoire/Fairy Heart: It's about a cursed girl and the cursed boy.

In the last few panels,

> Zeref and she are shown - and she's about to lean against him.

I think that's a quite clear hint on their relationship.